# I am getting an additional message after I ran server of windows shell

Tags: python, django, windows, web-development-server

Though I am successfully able to run my server from shell but I also got one more message with that . I am attaching the message below. Help me figure it out what it really wants to say and will it create any problems in the future for me?

[10/Oct/2020 05:11:37] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 16348
[10/Oct/2020 05:11:37] "GET /static/admin/css/fonts.css HTTP/1.1" 200 423
[10/Oct/2020 05:11:37] "GET /static/admin/fonts/Roboto-Regular-webfont.woff HTTP/1.1" 200 80304
[10/Oct/2020 05:11:37] "GET /static/admin/fonts/Roboto-Light-webfont.woff HTTP/1.1" 200 81348
[10/Oct/2020 05:11:37] "GET /static/admin/fonts/Roboto-Bold-webfont.woff HTTP/1.1" 200 82564
Not Found: /favicon.ico
[10/Oct/2020 05:11:37] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 1978

Answer (score 0):

It is not an error. It is a missing favicon.ico
Favicon is the shortcut icon or logo that you see in the tab next to your title or even in the bookmarks at times. Its kind of related to your site identity.

You can upload your site logo or any image here and generate a favicon.ico file - https://www.favicon-generator.org/

Then upload it to your static folder and paste this code in your base.html header

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="{% static 'favicon.ico' %}"/>
```